# Using multiple GROUP BYs to get fewer records, not more

Tags: mariadb, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I feel like this is a simple thing to do, but I've been playing around with trying to achieve the desired result and the only way I'm coming up is with 2 nested subqueries, which doesn't seem great from a performance perspective.

I have a table called `billing` which is currently 60,000 rows and growing at an increasing rate, with maybe 100 or 200 new entries per day.

Here is a query I wrote that returns exactly what I want:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS calls, tmp.*
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time,
                        b.clli, u.city, u.state
                    FROM  nrt.billing AS b
                    LEFT JOIN  users AS u  ON b.switchowner = u.id
                    ORDER BY  b.id DESC
                    LIMIT  18446744073709551615
            ) AS tmp
            GROUP BY  clli
            ORDER BY  bid DESC
            LIMIT  18446744073709551615
    ) AS tmp2
    GROUP BY  uid
    ORDER BY  bid DESC
```

(The LIMIT weirdness is a MariaDB hack to make it behave like MySQL.)

I initially had just:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS calls, tmp.*
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time, b.clli, u.city, u.state
            FROM  nrt.billing AS b
            LEFT JOIN  users AS u  ON b.switchowner = u.id
            ORDER BY  b.id DESC
            LIMIT  18446744073709551615
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY  clli
    ORDER BY  bid DESC`
```

... and that worked mostly all right. What I am trying to do is get one record per `clli` column, the newest once for each (hence with the highest ID). This gives me the newest record for every `clli` value there is. I do like the single subquery way of doing it as opposed to inner joining on a table with max values.

A slight problem is that the `clli` values sometimes (but rarely) change. In that case, I don't want the `clli` values that have been superseded. There is "effectively" a foreign key to the `users` table here, so I can associate `clli` values with user IDs. Of course, `GROUP BY clli, id` will give me every unique `clli`/`id` pairing, giving me *more* rows, the opposite of what I want. So, I nested the subqueries and did another `GROUP BY` to get only the latest `clli` per user ID.

Is there a way to optimize out the second nested subquery surrounding the first one? It seems like there should also be a way to combine the `GROUP BY`s in the other direction.

At 60,000 rows, and the `billing` table being much larger than `users`, this doesn't perform badly, but it just seems like a bad query to me. Can the second subquery be optimized out, or is this as good as I'll get with this approach?

Here is table structure:

```
describe billing;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| ani           | varchar(32)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| called_number | int(7)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| chargedfrom   | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| switchowner   | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| clli          | varchar(24)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                              |
| rt_time       | datetime         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

describe users;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |               |
| city            | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| state           | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I've omitted rows that are not relevant / used in these queries.

It isn't officially part of the structure, but billing.switchowner is used as a foreign key with users.id.

Here is a DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7y19T29CeykBSPFb7oJq9M/0

If that doesn't work, this will set up the fiddle:

````
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `billing` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `switchowner` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `clli` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
 `rt_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `users` (city, state) VALUES ("New York", "NY");
INSERT INTO `users` (city, state) VALUES ("Wilmington", "DE");
INSERT INTO `users` (city, state) VALUES ("San Francisco", "CA");
INSERT INTO `users` (city, state) VALUES ("Phoenix", "AZ");
INSERT INTO `users` (city, state) VALUES ("Houston", "TX");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK-01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK-01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("4", "PHNXAZ01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("4", "PHNXAZ01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("5", "HTX01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("2", "WILMDE01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("3", "SANFRAN01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("2", "WILMDE01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("5", "HTX01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("3", "SANFRAN01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("4", "PHNXAZ01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("3", "SANFRAN01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("1", "NEWYRK01");
INSERT INTO `billing` (switchowner, clli) VALUES ("3", "SANFRAN01");
SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, tmp.* FROM (
SELECT b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time, b.clli, u.city, u.state FROM billing
AS b LEFT JOIN users AS u ON b.switchowner = u.id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615)
AS tmp GROUP BY clli ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615)
AS tmp2 GROUP BY uid ORDER BY bid DESC;```
````

Comment: I get a strong feeling that tmp.* is not functionally determined by clli in your GROUP BY. If that suspicion is right your query will be non-deterministic. You can search for ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to find out more

Comment: @Lennart Ah, interesting. No, the query doesn't return any errors and the query does work. I manually inspected the tables and it returns the right rows in the right order. `switchowner` for any given `clli` should always be the same, but the reverse is not necessarily true - does that answer the question? In that sense, I don't think it would be non-deterministic, but maybe I missed something else.

Comment: @InterLinked, can you upgrade to 10.2?

Comment: "hack to make it behave like MySQL" -- The latest MySQL also needs the 'hack'.  But, as Lennart points out, your query is "invalid" and will lead to surprising results.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not valid SQL, it is only allowed if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is missing from @@sql_mode. I moved your example to [Fiddle1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cc7e78fe73ec081c717679586072817d) and tried. Note that I set

```
set @@sql_mode=concat(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');
```

and as a consequence `'tmp.bid' isn't in GROUP BY` is the error message you get from your query.

But, let's enable partial GROUP BY and see where that leads us. Your innermost query:

```
SELECT b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time, b.clli, u.city, u.state 
FROM billing AS b 
LEFT JOIN users AS u 
    ON b.switchowner = u.id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615;
```

returns 23 rows. So far so good. If we add another layer of nesting:

```
SELECT tmp.*, COUNT(*) AS calls FROM (
    SELECT b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time, b.clli, u.city, u.state 
    FROM billing AS b 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u 
        ON b.switchowner = u.id
    ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615
) AS tmp 
GROUP BY clli
```

This seems to work, but there is no rational explanation to why it should (AFAIK). Unless you find it clearly documented that it is guaranteed to work, I would not trust the result. Will it work when you upgrade to the next version?

Starting with 10.2 you can use window functions. They are a much better alternative if you can upgrade to that version:

```
SELECT bid, uid, rt_time, clli, city, state, calls
FROM (
    SELECT b.id AS bid, u.id AS uid, b.rt_time, b.clli, u.city, u.state
         , row_number() over (partition by b.clli order by b.id desc) as rn
         , count(1) over (partition by b.clli) as calls
    FROM billing AS b 
    LEFT JOIN users AS u 
        ON b.switchowner = u.id
) as tmp
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY clli, bid;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3807ed17455298ebfa8e7d032abe6214) for MariaDB 10.3

Comment: It is expected behavior, see the comment by Roberto here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Upgrading is in the works, but as it's more complicated than something like a PHP upgrade, it's something that's not high up on the priority list due to time constraints.

Comment: I played with your fiddle, and I modified the last one because I don't want it to ORDER on the clli at all, it should be purely descending order for b.id/bid. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0488ce51da77c3d77c499a30540b9778 - one thing I see that the row with bid 2 appears, and it should **not** appear in the output. That's why I was grouping by clli, to get only one row per clli. Is that doable with the windowing? It seems less easy to read than a subquery to me, but is it more performant? Just curious why that is a better option. Thank you!

Comment: First it is standard and works with any vendor. I see now that one row disappeared due to the group by uid. I'm highly confused by this, what is the expected result if uid=1 moves to HTX01?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8d3865d9c208e05eb43e46044f66abbb  I added the row INSERT INTO billing (switchowner, clli) VALUES (1, 'HTX01'); last

Comment: For a given user ID, the clli code might change but never to an already existing clli code used by another user ID. But technically, it would be seen as an override, and then there would only be 4 rows in the expected table, instead of 5 or 6, since HTX01 will have superseded all New York entries.

Comment: Your query corresponds to last query on: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=20de73c3217b311f9167dffe28d50385